# Two forms, two views, one page Django - only one form displays

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have two separate forms stemming from the same model (CustomUser). I want to have two separate forms with separate buttons to break the EditProfile form down into two forms on the same page. I created two separate forms, two views and two urls. I also added two separate actions to the forms, but I can only get the first form to display. I tried adding both the name of the url and the name of the view function in the action, but it didn't work.

views.py:

```
def EditProfileView(request):
form = EditProfile()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfile(request.POST, instance =request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit_profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfile(instance = request.user)

    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {
        'form': form,
    })


def EditProfileDetailView(request):
form = EditProfileDetail()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileDetail(request.POST, instance =request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfileDetail(instance = request.user)
    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

path('profile/edit/', views.EditProfileView, name='edit_profile'),
path('profile/edit/', views.EditProfileDetailView, 
      name='edit_profile_detail'),

]
```

forms.py:

```
class EditProfile(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields =('diff_field', 'diff_field2',)

class EditProfileDetail(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields =('skill_area1_title', 'skill_area1',)
```

edit_profile.html:

```
<form  class="form-group booking_form"  method="post" action="{% url 
   'edit_profile' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  #form stuff
 </form>



<form  class="form-group booking_form"  method="post" action="{% url 
   'edit_profile_detail' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  #form stuff 
 </form>
```

***Updated view based on comment below***

```
def EditProfileView(request):
form = EditProfile()
form_two =EditProfileDetail()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfile(request.POST, instance =request.user)
    form_two = EditProfileDetail(request.POST, instance =request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('edit_profile'))
    if form_two.is_valid():
        form_two.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile'))
else:
    form = EditProfile(instance = request.user)
    form_two = EditProfileDetail(instance = request.user)

    return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {
        'form': form,
        'form_two': form_two,
    })
```

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You **cannot** have two views for a single URL.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful. I've now created one view and one url, however I want separate redirects for the two forms upon submitting. I have two if statements in my view with form.save() separate redirects, but it only uses the first redirect. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I've added the view that I'm referring to above.

Comment: Because once you return from a function, the function ends. The `if form_two.is_valid()` is never reached. Did you mean the first `return` to be inside that `if form.is_valid()` block?

Comment: Yes! thank you so much! I need to brush up on my basic programming skills.